# Nested viewmodel in asp.net mvc - calculated field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel shown below.

For each RateList - it can have a number of Occ objects linked to it.

What I'm trying to do in Occs.occval is to return a concatenated string which takes TypeName from the parent RatesList model, and concatenates it to the occdesk property in the Occ = ie. `return occdesc + "||" + RatesList.TypeName;` but I get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is there any way to achieve this in the model below?

Thank you,

Mark

```
    public class RatesList
    {
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string TypeDesc { get; set; }
    public int TypeCount { get; set; }

    public virtual IQueryable<Occ> Occs { get; set; }
    public string OccSelected { get; set; }

    }

    public class Occ
    {
    public string occdesc { get; set; }
    public string occval { 
     get
        {
            return occdesc + "||" + RatesList.TypeName;
        }
    }
    public int numOfOcc { get; set; }
    public virtual RatesList RatesList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you passing the parent (RatesList) when creating the Occs?

Comment: Hi - I don't know that I am - I just assumed as Occ was a property of RatesList in the model, that Occ would somehow be able to read the parent properties of RatesList.  Is that incorrect?  Thank you, Mark

Comment: It cannot read the properties of an object which is null (RatesList). You have to assign the parent to Occ.RatesList before you can access its properties.